# Angular 4/5 как отобразить символ &amp; как &?

Tags: angular2, angular4, angular5

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safeHTML'
})
export class SafeHTMLPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  }
  transform(style) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(style);
  }
}

<h3 class="m-2" [innerHTML]="Object.name | safeHTML"></h3>
```

выводит `&amp;`

Comment: В AppModule в declarations не забыли добавить SafeHTMLPipe?

Comment: нет конечно ....

Comment: Вы так неоднозначно ответили, что я вынуждена уточнить, что вы имели в виду :) `Нет, не добавил, после добавления всё заработало` или `Нет, было добавлено и всё равно не работает`

Comment: указать Pipe в declarations я не забыл, пайп выполняется. только вот не делает то что нужно

Comment: А в строке что находится?

Comment: текст, html теги и всякие там &amp;  &quot;. хотя конкретно в той что в примере  просто текст типа "title &amp; header"

Comment: Может `transform(value: string): SafeHtml {return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);}` ?

Comment: нет, так тоже не работает

Comment: что никто не знает? О.О

Comment: @JohnDoe, он и так отображается как амперсанд :)

Comment: хм и правда, видать что-то пофиксили. потому что с тех пор как я этот вопрос запостил я обновился с 5го на 6й ангуляр